# YUM crashed due to library missing

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, rpm

I tried to remove stock Lua and build my own one, so I tried:

```
yum remove lua
```

But too many dependencies on the package and it does not allow me to remove it so I used rpm instead:

```
rpm -r --nodeps --force lua
```

It removed Lua. Then I built my own one. However yum crashes from now on, and every time I run yum (does not matter if it is yum install or yum list, or just yum), it gives me

```
error:There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   liblua-5.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.3 (default, Aug  9 2012, 17:23:57) 
[GCC 4.7.1 20120720 (Red Hat 4.7.1-5)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I cannot even install lua back because it does not allow me to run. `rpm` is crashed too:

```
rpm: error while loading shared libraries: liblua-5.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have a version of liblua-5.1.so, but I tried to put the symbolic link in /usr/lib, and /usr/local/lib, it still gives this error. Please help... I do not want to reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear `yum` depends on a specific version of the *Lua* library shared object file (liblua-5.1.so). The compile flags you used when compiling your own version of the library seem to be incompatible.

Therefore you should determine your architecture (`uname -m`) then download the lua [i686](http://fedora.c3sl.ufpr.br/linux/releases/19/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/l/lua-5.1.4-12.fc19.i686.rpm) or [x86_64](http://fedora.c3sl.ufpr.br/linux/releases/19/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/lua-5.1.4-12.fc19.x86_64.rpm) package from Fedora and install it with `rpm` to restore `yum` to a working order.

---

If you are unable to use `rpm` then obtain a *Fedora LiveCD/LiveUSB*. You will `chroot` into your install and attempt repairs. Here are some **guidelines**:

**Determine which partition your Fedora / is on**

```
sudo -i
blkid
```

**Mount your Fedora partition**

```
arch="i686"
mntDir="/mnt"
mount /dev/sdX# "$mntDir"
rpm -i lua-5.1.4-12.fc19.${arch}.rpm --prefix "$mntDir"
```

**Chroot into install**

```
mount -t proc proc "${mntDir}/proc/"
mount -t sysfs sys "${mntDir}/sys/"
mount -o bind /dev "${mntDir}/dev/"
mount -t devpts pts "${mntDir}/dev/pts"
chroot "$mntDir" /bin/bash
```

**Debug install**

```
yum --help
```

Comment: hi whenever I run rpm, it gives me error so basically im not able to install anything... even locally

Comment: Did you try the LiveCD + chroot?

Comment: I ended up using similar thing... used a live cd and yum --installroot /mnt lua.x64_64 and its fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. My system is CentOS 6.

Solution:

1. Find another CentOS 6 system that without yum command problem.
2. Find where is `liblua-5.1.so`.

```
$ whereis liblua-5.1.so
$ liblua-5.1: /usr/lib64/liblua-5.1.so
```

3. Copy `/usr/lib64/liblua-5.1.so` to your problematic system same path `/usr/lib64/liblua-5.1.so`